# How to remove take property lower value in object?

Tags: arrays

I have this array of objects and I need to remove duplicates. Removing duplicates works great. However I need to add a condition that if a property value is lower than another one then just take the lower value.

can anyone tell me what my condition should look like:

Here's my working code:

```js
function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
     var newArray = [];
     var lookupObject  = {};

     for(var i in originalArray) {
        lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
     }

     for(i in lookupObject) {
         newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
     }
      return newArray;
 }
 
 var arr = [{"id": 1, "val": 0},{"id": 2, "val": 0},{"id": 3, "val": 0},{"id": 1, "val": 1}];
 var myNewArray = removeDuplicates(arr, 'id');
 console.log(myNewArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to compare the `.val` properties:

```js
 function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
   var newArray = [];
   var lookupObject = {};

   // Modified lines
   for (var i in originalArray) {
     let item = lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]];
     if (!item || item.val > originalArray[i].val) {
       lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
     }
   }

   for (i in lookupObject) {
     newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
   }
   return newArray;
 }

 var arr = [{
   "id": 1,
   "val": 0
 }, {
   "id": 2,
   "val": 0
 }, {
   "id": 3,
   "val": 0
 }, {
   "id": 1,
   "val": 1
 }];
 var myNewArray = removeDuplicates(arr, 'id');
 console.log(myNewArray);
```

Note that you should avoid using `for ... in` for iterating through arrays!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if originalArray[i]; is already on the lookup object and then use the min() function between the already on the lookup value and the current in the loop to set the value.
Something like this:

```
function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
     var newArray = [];
     var lookupObject  = {};

     for(var i in originalArray) {
        if (originalArray[i][prop] in lookupObject) {
            lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = Math.max(lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]], originalArray[i])
        } else {
            lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
        }

     }

     for(i in lookupObject) {
         newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
     }
      return newArray;
 }

 var arr = [{"id": 1, "val": 0},{"id": 2, "val": 0},{"id": 3, "val": 0},{"id": 1, "val": 1}];
 var myNewArray = removeDuplicates(arr, 'id');
 console.log(myNewArray);
```